# Find $x$ given remainder conditions

Tags: divisibility

The problem: **Find the smallest positive integer $x$ such that**

*$x$ divided by $4$ has remainder $1$*

*$x$ divided by $5$ has reminder $2$*

*$x$ divided by $6$ has remainder $3$*

Now, my first idea was to add to each divisor its the remainder and multiply the quantities obtained.

$x=(4+1)(5+2)(6+3)=315$

But $315$ does not satisfy all the conditions above, and I don't know how to get the smallest integer that satisfies the conditions. Any help?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [congruence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation#Basic_example) on the integers?

Comment: Yes but im not fan of them

Comment: $315$ is neither the smallest number that works, nor is it even one such number. $315$ leaves a remainder of $0$ when divided by $5$ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x \equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then $$x \equiv 1,5,9,13,17\pmod{20}$$ Of these, only $17$ is also $2 \pmod{5}$. Therefore 
$$x \equiv 17 \pmod{20}$$

Next, the LCM of $20$ and $6$ is $60$.

If $x \equiv 17 \pmod{20}$, then $$x \equiv 17, 37, 57 \pmod{60}$$

Of these, only $57$ is $3\pmod{6}$. This means

$$x \equiv 57\pmod{60}$$

This means $\boxed{57}$ is the smallest $x$ that satisfies your conditions.

Comment: Note that this method also finds *all* $x$ that satisfy your conditions. Simply add any multiple of $60$ to $57$ to get other values of $x$ that will work.

Answer (score 0):

You may have solved problems of the kind: *Find x such that it leaves a remainder 3 when divided by 4, 5 or 6.*

In the above scenario you first find out a number which divisible by each of 4, 5 and 6 (lcm or it's multiple) and then you add the remainder 3 to that number. You can find infinitely many such numbers as there are infinite number of multiples of $lcm(4,5,6)$.

Here notice that $4-1 = 3$, $5-2 = 3$ and $6-3 = 3$. So basically we are solving the exactly same problem here, we have just changed the remainder from $3$ to $-3$.

As $lcm(4,5,6) = 60$, such numbers are of form $60n - 3$, for any integer $n$.